# How to automatically show the keyboard in a search view

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, searchview

**I found so many questions about this topic and so many solutions, but none of them worked.** I'll try asking the question again.

This is a **search fragment** inside which the toolbar has a search view. My **purpose** is to **show the user** who arrives at this fragment, the **keyboard automatically**.

The focus in the search view is present in that when the fragment is opened, the cursor appears in the search view.

**What really doesn't want to go is showing the keyboard.**

Here is how I tried this with the code snippet and source:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SearchFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentSearchBinding>() {

    private val viewModel: SearchViewModel by viewModels()
    override val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup?, Boolean) -> FragmentSearchBinding
        get() = FragmentSearchBinding::inflate

    override fun initializeViews() {

        //other code
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.searchView.focusAndShowKeyboard()// <-- The Extension function
    }


}
```

The method in question is in the **BaseFragment** superclass and is as follows (*[Here](https://developer.squareup.com/blog/showing-the-android-keyboard-reliably/#showing-the-keyboard) is the source of the method*):

```
protected fun View.focusAndShowKeyboard() {
        /**
         * This is to be called when the window already has focus.
         */
        fun View.showTheKeyboardNow() {
            if (isFocused) {
                post {
                    // We still post the call, just in case we are being notified of the windows focus
                    // but InputMethodManager didn't get properly setup yet.
                    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                    imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
                }
            }
        }

        requestFocus()
        if (hasWindowFocus()) {
            // No need to wait for the window to get focus.
            showTheKeyboardNow()
        } else {
            // We need to wait until the window gets focus.
            viewTreeObserver.addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(
                object : ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener {
                    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
                        // This notification will arrive just before the InputMethodManager gets set up.
                        if (hasFocus) {
                            this@focusAndShowKeyboard.showTheKeyboardNow()
                            // It’s very important to remove this listener once we are done.
                            viewTreeObserver.removeOnWindowFocusChangeListener(this)
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
    }
```